# Object tracking, avoid collision and current velocity of two objects

Tags: java, opencv, collision-detection

I need an image taken by Kinect camera to be evaluated in order to detect whether two moving objects will collide. The shape, size and colour of the moving objects are known in advance.

My task is:

- The current position of the two objects
- Current velocity of each of the two objects

I am doing this project on Opencv and Java, and I am able to track two coloured objects from laptop web camera and Kinect.

How can I find current position and velocity of two objects?

Comment: velocity is a distance per time kind of thing... you can't do it from one picture

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically seen you need to have two pictures, then you can divide the distance by the time.

double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((objectbefore.x-objectafter.x), 2) + Math.pow((objectbefore.y-objectafter.y), 2))

The Timer object counts in Integers in java so:

int time = Timer.getTime()(after) - Timer.getTime()(before) (this isn't correct in java but you'll get my intention)

Comment: thank you so much your suggestion, now i am trying to find current position of moving objects in every pixel. It is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

That depends if you move your object pixel per pixel you can. Let me just explain it a bit to you. If made an object, example:

```
Rectangle block = new Rectangle(block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height);
```

You also need to have a Timer object to let it move:

```
java.util.Timer time;
time.schedule(task, delay, period);
```

Then you should make a dependency between object time and object block. Once that is done you can make the block moving. At any moment you can ask the block.x or block.y (block's position) and you can ask time too with some method. So you can actualy mesure the velocity.

Comment: Thank you so much your help, later on i will update my project status.